# Docker - Error starting daemon

Tags: arch-linux, docker, daemon

I have tried to install Docker to my RPI on Arch Linux and got the following error message, when try to start a new container.

> FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: Error initializing network
>   controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: package not
>   installed

How can I run daemon?

Comment: Docker version? Arch version?

Comment: Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d
Linux alarmpi 3.12.28-2-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Mon Sep 22 02:02:11 MDT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux

Comment: Which method did you use to install Docker?  Have you ensured Docker's prerequisite [dependency packages](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/docker/) are installed (e.g.: [Utilities for configuring the Linux ethernet bridge](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/bridge-utils/))?

Comment: All the dependencies are exists now, but same error message here.

Comment: Have you tried to build the bridge manually [https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#building-your-own-bridge](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#building-your-own-bridge)

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting. I read it's necessary after installing bridge-utils. I had the same problem and rebooting did the trick for me.